# nodeJS: using (fs) to try and access a static resource but receive 404 error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, fs

I'm trying to generate a url using nodeJS that points to a static resource, which is a JS file. It throws me a 404 error, Not Found.

First I start the node server with `node index.js`

**The node.js file has this:**

```
var fs = require('fs');

function serveStaticFile(res, path, contentType, responseCode) {
    if(!responseCode) responseCode = 200;
    fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end('500 - Internal Error');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(responseCode,
                    {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
            res.end(data);
        }
    });
}

http.createServer(function(req,res){

    var path = req.url.toLowerCase();
    switch(path) {
        case '/avisarPagoAhora':
                serveStaticFile(res, '/avisoPago/avisos-de-pago.html', 'text/html');
                break;
        default:
                res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                res.end('Not Found');
                break;      
    }


}).listen(3000);

console.log('Server started on localhost:3000; press Ctrl-C to terminate...');
```

Now, I've got index.js inside var/www/html/avisoPago

And my avisos-de-pago.html file is inside the avisoPago folder that's inside avisoPago.

So the path to index.js is: **var/www/html/avisoPago/index.js**

And the path to avisos-de-pago.html file is: **var/www/html/avisoPago/avisoPago/avisos-de-pago.html**

**What Am I doing wong that it doesn't find the file when I type http://myDomain:3000/avisarPagoAhora**

Comment: Do a `console.log(__dirname + path)` to see what file it's actually looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var path = req.url.toLowerCase();` The "toLowerCase" function makes the "avisarPagoAhora" turn into "avisarpagoahora" and because of it node can't find the right path `'/avisarPagoAhora'`. Try to remove the toLowerCase function or make the case statement "`case '/avisarpagoahora':`"